# Datatable - Import multiple tables to a single sheet in excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, datatable

Is it possible to import a multiple table result into a single excel sheet using jquery Datatable?

I found this example on other questions but he did a different function. But this is also the desired result i want

Sample

[image: 1]

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the reference link for 'I found this example on other questions' ., where did you find it ., post the link?